# Object Shows up in the rendered tab but not in the actual render

Tags: rendering

I am new to blender and have been following Blender Guru's beginner tutorial series. I just finished my coffee cup and went to render it and it does not show up, but it will show up in the rendered tab.[image: Rendered View][image: Solid View][image: Rendered]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cup influencing plane, but is not visible.

[image]

Check your render layer settings:

**On the left** - all active layers

**On the right** - active layers for "RenderLayer" named render layer. You have one of them (with cup) switched OFF. That's why cup influence scene, but is not visible.